# Regular space and regular open sets

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be regular if for every $x\in X$ and every closed set $F$ not containing $x$ there exists $U,V\in\tau$ such that $x\in U$, $F\subset V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

A regular open set is an open set $U$ such that $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(U))=U$.

I tried to find a regular topological space whose only regular open set is $X$ and $\emptyset$, but I tried all the topological spaces I know, but I could not find it except indiscrete topology with more thab2 elements, maybe there is no such thing as this topological space which is regular and admits only $X$ and $\emptyset$ as regular open set except indiscrete topology.

I am so confused and my heart is broken actually. Any help will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim.** A topological space $X$ has no regular opens other than $X$ and $\emptyset$ if and only if there is no pair of non-empty disjoint opens in $X$.

**Proof.** Left to right, if there are no regular opens other than $X$ and $\emptyset$, then for each non-empty open $U$ we have $\mathrm{cl}(U) = X$, since otherwise $\emptyset \subsetneq U \subseteq \mathrm{int} (\mathrm{cl} (U)) \subsetneq X$. In other words, $\mathrm{int}(X \setminus U) = \emptyset$, so there is no non-empty open $V$ disjoint from $U$. Right to left, if there is no pair of disjoint opens, then for each non-empty open $U$ we have $\mathrm{int}(X \setminus U) = \emptyset$, so $\mathrm{cl}(U) = X$ and $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(U)) = X$. Thus $U$ is not regular unless $U = X$.

**Non-example.** No regular space which is not indiscrete satisfies this condition: if $F$ is a non-empty and non-total closed set, then regularity produces disjoint non-empty opens.

**Non-example.** No Hausdorff space with at least two points satisfies this condition: if $x$ and $y$ are distinct points, then the Hausdorff axiom produces disjoint non-empty opens.

**Example.** Each space where the [specialization preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialization_(pre)order) is upward directed satisfies this condition. For example, the [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) of an upward directed partially ordered set satisfies this condition, as does the topology on the reals consisting of intervals of the form $(a, +\infty)$ plus the empty and total set.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But actually I guess I missed The examples you gave for ? So I can not find a regular space whose only regular open sets are only empty set and the total set? If so, there is no non-empty disjoint opens ? @Pilcrow

Comment: @Woodx I am afraid I don't understand your comment. I just gave you an example, namely the reals with the topology where the opens are intervals of the form $(a, +\infty)$ plus the empty set and the total set. The closure of each non-empty open in this topology is the total set.

Comment: Okay thank you so much, but this space is not a regular space right ? @Pilcrow

Comment: Actually my Question is this, the space is regular space and whose only regular open sets are the total set and the empty set only, can we find any such space other than Indiscrete topological space ? @Pilcrow

Comment: @Woodx I am sorry, I was careless and missed that part of your question. I just edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: So there is no such thing as topological space except indiscrete topological space? @Pilcrow

Comment: @Woodx Correct. If you have a non-empty non-total closed set, the regularity condition produces two disjoint opens $U$ and $V$, which implies that $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(U))$ is a non-empty non-total regular open.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your effort sir, appreciated. @Pilcrow

Answer (score 2):

$(X, \tau) $ be a topological space.

1. $\emptyset, X$ are two trivial regular open sets.
2. Every regular open sets are open.

Consider indidcerete topology on $X$ where $|X|>2$.

Then $(X, \tau) $ is a regular space having only two trivial regular open sets ( as only open sets are $\emptyset, X$)

Comment: Actually I knew that, any other example you know? @SouravGhosh